# Выбор цвета и присваивание его элементу

Tags: jquery

Добрый день!

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать присваивание класса с определенным цветом блоку.

Необходимо, чтобы по клику на список цветов (на панели) цвет присваивался блоку с классом .wrapper.

Вот структура - http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/jcTmA/

Comment: [Так не будут классы теряться](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/jcTmA/2/)

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, подскажите пожалуйста, как при этом задать класс активному элементу?

    .bg-active { border: 1px solid #fff; }

Comment: [Так](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/jcTmA/3/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так как-то:

```
$('.switch').on('click', function(e) {
    var color = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0];
    $('.wrapper').attr('class', 'wrapper ' + color);
});
```

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Подскажите пожалуйста, для чего нужна буква e в папаметре функции и что она обозначает.

Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: Внимательно вчитываеися в документацию функции [`on()`][1] и узнаём, что это - объект, описывающий атрибуты события, которое должен обработать наш обработчик. В данном случае он не используется (и его можно было не указывать), но для некоторых событий важно узнать детали (например, для события `keypress` - какая кнопка была нажата), и тогда используется этот объект.

  [1]: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @fori1ton, спасибо.

Comment: @fori1ton, а подскажите пожалуйста, почему после применения данного кода, теряются другие слассы присвоенные элементу .wrapper?

Comment: Метод `attr()` с двумя входными параметрами перезаписывает значение атрибута элемента (в данном случае `class`). Я жёстко задал, что класс элемента `wrapper` будет заменён на `'wrapper ' + color`. Если вам нужно схранить другие классы, запомните их и добавьте в этой строке.

Comment: [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/), [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/), [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).